# Laptop does not boot from usb memory at all

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb

I put USB in the boot order first and I tried to select it from the boot menu, but it boots only from hdd every time. I have an USB3 stick 32 GB and created t a bootable stick with startup disk creator under Ubuntu 11.10. Does anyone out there know what's going wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated !!

Thank you all,
          Stefan

Comment: Yes and I used a ubuntu 12.10 32bit iso image of course

Answer (score 0):

Do you have usb2 port in your computer? Try to use it.

Comment: What do you mean? I have the usb stick sitting there. The computer can also read from it under ubuntu 11.10 but does not boot

Comment: He means there may be problem booting off a USB 3 port.  Since you say you are using a USB 3 stick, the implication is that you have it plugged into a USB 3 port.  If so, and you have some USB 2.0 ports then try to use one of them instead.